# Sql Server: decimal storage issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, decimal

Will decimal(18,2) use more storage than decimal(6,2) even if the actual value is 34.25?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage required is defined by the precision and scale that you've defined in your table.

See [the MSDN documentation on the `decimal` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

With `decimal(18, 2)` in your case, you'll use **9 bytes** - regardless of what value is stored in that column.

With `decimal(6, 2)`, you would be using **5 bytes**.

SQL Server 2008 and higher in the Enterprise (or Developer) SKU have a `vardecimal` flag, too, that enables optimizing the storage of decimal values. [Read more about it here at the SQL Server Storage engine team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/11/13/enabling-vardecimal-storage-format.aspx)